# integrating shiny to another web page

Tags: javascript, html, r, shinyapps, shinyjs

I have created a web page using R packages in Shiny web application and have published it to shiny.io. What can I do to include this page to be a sub-page of another website and make some possible interactions with the Javascript functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed your Shiny App in a web page with the iframe tag like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>Shiny App Iframe</title></head>
<body>
<iframe src="URL of your shiny app at shinyapps.io" style="border: none; width: 100%; height: 850px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```